# Wrong-placed repaints?

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, raster

I'm writing Microsoft's paint. The problem is that on bigger pictures (even on 800x600 pic) fragment of this pic appears unwanted in random places on bitmap. It is uneditable, you cannot draw on it. It covers old content. Additionally, it uses the same data source as my pic, so editing bitmap causes edit of this fragment (but not inversely). Don't know where did it come from and how to remove it. I suppose I might have placed repaint() and revalidate() in wrong places.

I'm attaching a screenshot which describes what i'm talking about. If someone is interested in helping me, please write something down and I'll give you necessary code.

Screen: http://postimage.org/image/xaa7udgmp/

Comment: That happens when you resize window from scroll-bars?

Comment: problem occurs when window is maximized or it's dimensions are similar to maximized

Comment: You computer is low-end?

Comment: well, surprisingly on my laptop it's working fine (quite bad computer), but when i tested app in other computer (definitelly not low-end) the problem occured

Comment: No problem on your notebook but problem on other computer? Lets find hardware/OS dependencies. a little code wouldnt hurt :)

Comment: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29b0

Comment: don't go that way. that cannot be hardware issue, cause friends run the app on their computers and it also didn't work fine

Comment: repaint(); is not synchronised and mousemoved(listener) changes X an Y coordinates without synchronising. Can you put them in Synchronised(this){} ?

Comment: done. but nothing happend. what can i also say is that this fragment of image sometimes is bigger, sometimes wider, sometimes occurs in other places. it changes it size and location randomly after every repaint() so even every mouse movement
PS. fragment is usually subimage of right corner of the proper image

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).